# Expanding the width for one table column

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS for my table:-

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;

  word-wrap: break-word;


}
.table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

And inside my table i need to expand the width for my last column , i tried defining a custom width for it as follow, but it did not work :-

```
 <td id = "@item.RESOURCEID" style="width:30%">
```

currently my table looks as follow:-
[image]

Comment: You are looking for `rowspan`

Comment: you can try setting width in pixel like this: <td id = "@item.RESOURCEID" width="30">

Comment: @Mr.Alien . i think rowspan will expand vertically , while i need to expand the table column horizontally

Comment: @akshay i tried this <td id = "@item.RESOURCEID" style="width:300px"> .but still the table column have the same width ? can you advice ?

Comment: @johnG please try as I mention, It should work. I use it many times.

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/We9BG/1/) but I don't see the problem. It works fine.

Comment: @akshay `width="30"` is by no means a substitution for `style="width:30%"`

Comment: but width="30" did not work in my case ..